# вместо картинки в БД сохраняется id картинки

Tags: php, mysql, html5, phpmyadmin

Как из БД получить ссылку на картинку ? в БД сохраняется id картинки.

введите сюда описание изображения[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сама картинка(картинки) где хранится?

Comment: (/view/cache/c5c2c5e32ff400d7549f1e291a35c548) вот такой путь картинки

Comment: По сути, у вас 2 варианта.. Либо сохранять в БД путь, либо по ид подставлять его при рендере страницы

Comment: а как сохранить путь а не id картинки в БД

Comment: Поискать функцию, которая генерит путь до картинки по переданному id. 99,9%, что она там уже есть.

Answer (score 0):

> /view/cache/c5c2c5e32ff400d7549f1e291a35c548
>   Эта картинка выводится уже из кеша.

Лучше хранить имя файла (можно с расширением, можно без (лучше с расширением))
И уже во вьюхе генерировать полный путь. 
Для этого найдите где хранятся уже загруженные изображения.
Если это cms или фреймворк, то скорее всего уже есть методы позволяющие получить путь к папке с картинками (типа такого **$this->getMediaPath()**).
Тогда у вас выйдет что-то в духе: 
`<img src="<?php echo $this->getMediaPath() . $arsky['imgFileId'] ?>"`
Или сами укажите путь:
`<?php $imgMediaDir = '/your/path/to_image/'; ?>`
`<img src="<?php echo $imgMediaDir . $arsky['imgFileId'] ?>"`

Comment: сайт сделан на mvc. У меня не получается хранить имя файла.

Comment: mvc - самопис? 
"У меня не получается хранить имя файла"
Если изображения уже добавлены, то не нужно менять их загрузку (если не стоит такой задачи). Если ImageFileId - это не имя файла, значит есть отдельная таблица, где по этому id вы по идее можете получить и остальные данные изображения.

Comment: я нашел таблицу где есть имена картинок. можешь подсказать как получить картинку из этой таблицы (я добавил фото таблицы )

Comment: Найдите место, где выводится хотя бы одна картинка и посмотрите как делается выборка из БД. ( там модель должна обращаться к БД и делать выборку)
Если вас интересует сам запрос, то выглядеть будет примерно так:
``SELECT `filename` FROM `your_table_with_img` WHERE fileID = '4064'``
P.S.Если сайт сделан с использованием паттерна MVC, то как уже писал, работа с БД происходит через модели. Ищите как выводятся уже ранее добавленные картинки, чтобы не изобретать велосипед.